# Tool to backup Windows Azure ACS Namespace

Tags: azure, backup, wif, acs

We are making extensive usage of the ACS web api to configure our relying parties and identity providers.  This works great.  To shield ourselves from programmatic errors, we would like to be able to make a backup of the acs configuration : relying parties, identity providers, rules, keys ...
We could probably write this backup ourselves but I wonder if there are any tools available to backup/restore an acs namespace ?  There used to be some powershell cmdlets but these seem to have been removed from their locations.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no real out-of-the-box solution to take a backup of an azure acs namespace.  We have therefore resorted to writing some code that queries the acs namespace using the odata service.  For each of the exposed entities (relying parties, identity providers, ...) we perform a query and store the result in a Json file.  The complete result is quite readable and compact.  Since we had already all the code to access the odata service this was actually a question of an hour or two to write.
Restoring the backup will be slightly more challenging but at least we still have all the information to restore it (the difficulty is the order in which the entities need to be created).
It's a real pitty we have to write this ourselves.  The main problem will be if the object model gets updated since we won't have a backup of any future properties that might be added.  I would really have liked to have a backup possibility in windows azure itself.  But then again, life is never perfect.

Comment: Just for the curious;  By default th eodata queries to ACS only return 50 "records".  So you need to write a loop yourself to get more data.